# Using spring webflux to consume two apis one after another

Tags: spring-webflux

I need to write a new api which will take some parameters, consume and existing api and then use the results of this to consume a second existing api.
I haven't used spring 5 before but I've noticed that rest template is going to be deprecated and I should instead be using webflux.
I've done some tutorials on the simple cases but not sure how to acheive my specific problem.

Given I have the following two apis:

```
@GetMapping("/foo/{id}")
public Foo getById(@PathVariable int id) {
    return new Foo(id, "foo");
}

@PostMapping("/bar")
public Bar createBar(@RequestBody Bar bar) {
    return bar;
}
```

And I have a new springboot app containing the new api:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class ReactiveClientApplication {
    @Bean
    WebClient fooWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/foo")
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient barWebClient() {
        return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/bar")
            .build();
    }

    // This works fine
    @PostMapping("/foo/{fooId}")
    public Mono<Foo> foo(@PathVariable Integer fooId) {
        return fooWebClient()
            .get()
            .uri("/{id}", fooId)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Foo.class);
    }

    // This works fine
    @PostMapping("/bar")
    public Mono<Bar> bar() {
        return barWebClient()
            .post()
            .body(Mono.just(new Bar("bar", new Date())), Bar.class)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(Bar.class);
    }

    // I cannot get this to work
    @PostMapping("/foobar/{fooId}")
    public Mono<Bar> fooBar(@PathVariable Integer fooId) {
        Mono<Foo> fooMono = fooWebClient().get().uri("/{id}", fooId).retrieve().bodyToMono(Foo.class);
        fooMono.flatMap(foo -> {
            Mono<Bar> barMono = barWebClient().post().body(Mono.just(new Bar(foo.getFooStuff(), new Date())), Bar.class)
                    .retrieve().bodyToMono(Bar.class);
            return barMono;
        });
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ReactiveClientApplication.class)
            .properties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", "8081"))
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

The foobar method needs to call and wait for the response of foo, use this to call bar and then wait for the response and return it.

I think I obviously need to put in a bit more effort in learning how all this works but I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction of how I should be doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what doesn't work? Do you get an exception? Is this returning something unexpected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not return null. What about the following code:

```
@PostMapping("/foobar/{fooId}")
public Mono<Bar> fooBar(@PathVariable Integer fooId) {
    Mono<Foo> fooMono = fooWebClient().get().uri("/{id}", fooId).retrieve().bodyToMono(Foo.class);
    return fooMono.flatMap(foo -> 
                 barWebClient()
                    .post()
                    .body(Mono.just(new Bar(foo.getFooStuff(), new Date())), Bar.class)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(Bar.class)
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.